# How to synchronize two trio co-routines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-trio

I'm going through [Trio tutorial](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#tutorial-example-tasks-intro) and I made an [echo-client](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#tutorial-echo-client-example) that sends message to an [echo server](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#tutorial-echo-server-example) for 10 seconds:

```
async def sender(client_stream, flag):
    print("sender: started!")
    end_time = time.time() + 10
    while time.time() < end_time:
        data = b"async can sometimes be confusing, but I believe in you!"
        print("sender: sending {!r}".format(data))
        await client_stream.send_all(data)
        await trio.sleep(0)
    flag = False
    print("Left the while 10 seconds loops")
```

and wait for responses while the `flag` is `True.

```
async def receiver(client_stream, flag):
    print("receiver: started!")
    while(flag):
        data = await client_stream.receive_some()
        print("receiver: got data {!r}".format(data))
    print("receiver: connection closed")
    sys.exit()
```

The problem is that sometimes the program hangs at line `data = await client_stream.receive_some()` because of concurrency issues with regards to the variable `flag`.

How do I send a signal from the `sender` co-routine to the `receiver` co-routine?

Here is the [entire program](https://gist.github.com/jenia/706d3d03bcc05806e96423184b0fcd41) that you can run.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't just sometimes hang there, it hangs all the time because the `flag` variable in `receiver()` never gets changed. I think you're under the impression that it's somehow shared between `receiver()` and `sender()`. It's not.

The simplest way you could fix that is by passing it in a container:

```
async def sender(client_stream, flag):
    print("sender: started!")
    end_time = time.time() + 10
    while time.time() < end_time:
        data = b"async can sometimes be confusing, but I believe in you!"
        print("sender: sending {!r}".format(data))
        await client_stream.send_all(data)
        await trio.sleep(0)
    flag[0] = False
    print("Left the while 10 seconds loops")

async def receiver(client_stream, flag):
    print("receiver: started!")
    while flag[0]:
        data = await client_stream.receive_some()
        print("receiver: got data {!r}".format(data))
    print("receiver: connection closed")
    sys.exit()

async def start_server():
    print("parent: connecting to 127.0.0.1:{}".format(PORT))
    client_stream = await trio.open_tcp_stream("127.0.0.1", PORT)
    flag = [False]
    async with client_stream:
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            print("parent: spawning sender...")
            nursery.start_soon(sender, client_stream, flag)

            print("parent: spawning receiver...")
            nursery.start_soon(receiver, client_stream, flag)
```

A more elegant solution would be closing the stream in `sender()` and catching `ClosedResourceError` in `receiver()`:

```
async def sender(client_stream):
    print("sender: started!")
    data = b"async can sometimes be confusing, but I believe in you!"
    with trio.move_on_after(10):
        print("sender: sending {!r}".format(data))
        await client_stream.send_all(data)

    await client_stream.aclose()
    print("Left the while 10 seconds loops")

async def receiver(client_stream):
    print("receiver: started!")
    try:
        async for data in client_stream:
            print("receiver: got data {!r}".format(data))
    except trio.ClosedResourceError:
        print("receiver: connection closed")
```

Notice how you don't even need `sys.exit()` for the program to end.

Comment: The second solution does not allow time for the receiver to read all the `sender` messages